# Choosing a random integer in a range such that it doesn't equal a particular number

Tags: refactoring, random

Given an integer range and a number within that range, what's a reasonably robust and efficient way to randomly select a new number within the range such that it's not equal to the given number?

Whenever I need to do this, I usually use something like:

```
// Randomly choose an integer within an inclusive range with the condition
// that the result not equal the previous number chosen
// INPUT: lastNum is an int in the range [minVal, maxVal]
int ChooseNewNumber(lastNum){

    minVal = 0;
    maxVal = N; // This would usually be a value like someContainer.size - 1
    intervalLength = maxVal - minVal + 1;

    // Assume RandomInt...() is an existing function that lives up to its name
    int newNum = RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(minVal, maxVal);

    if (newNum == lastNum){
        // Add a random offset to newNum and wrap around if necessary
        newNum = (newNum+RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(1, intervalLength - 1)) % (maxVal+1);
    }

    return newNum;
}
```

This works and it seems to avoid the introduction of any bias in the `newNum == lastNum` case, but it's a bit clunky. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing?

**EDIT:** as coredump pointed out, the method above fails if `minVal != 0`. Just for reference, the line:

```
newNum = (newNum+RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(1, intervalLength - 1)) % (maxVal+1);
```

should be:

```
new = ((new + RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(1, intervalLength - 1) - minVal) % intervalLength) + minVal;
```

I realize this mistake gave the impression that `minVal` might always be 0; sorry about that.

Comment: Instead of generating a number between `minVal` to `maxVal`, generate one from `minVal` to `maxVal - 1`, and if the number is equal to or greater than `lastNum`, increment it by one.  Granted, you don't want to do this with non-ints.  Also, you'll still need to do bounds checking and perhaps adjust for negative numbers being possible.  But, you'll only need to generate one number.

Comment: Do note that if the range actually stays the same and you simply want to sample without repetitions, it's usually done by creating an array of the range, [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) it and then just popping off the next number.

Comment: You probably want your random numbers to have a uniform distribution.  If this is so pick ractchet freak's answer.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald And why not my answer instead ;-) ? Isn't it equally uniform?

Comment: @coredump You answer is also equally uniform and fine, yet there is a small confusion between 0 and minval I guess.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald `minVal = 0`? This is as specified by the question; also, ratchet freak's answer starts with that exact assignment. I just inlined it.

Comment: @coredump … just inlined it. But why? Why? :D

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Why? They are constants: (1) The first and second lines are minVal=0, maxVal=N (2) maxVal is supposed to be "usually someContainer.size - 1", which makes 0 a natural value for minVal (3) If minVal and maxVal are not fixed, why aren't they passed as function argument? (4) *OP's own algorithm involves a modulo operation and doesn't even work if the interval does not start with 0* (!). Of course one can provide a more generic case (replace 0 with `minVal` and 1 with `minVal+1`), but I'm here to answer the question, as originally asked. KISS.

Comment: @coredump You took my question a bit too seriously! :)  I was just making fun of me being baffled by a quantity bearing two different names. :)

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald The joke went over my head, sorry :-)

Comment: @coredump Yeah, the algorithm I posted fails for `minVal != 0`, which is an oversight on my part. Although accessing a container is the most common scenario, it's possible that `minVal` might not be 0. However, I don't think this assumption detracts from your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just take a number in the range `[minVal, maxVal-1]` and add 1 if it is greater or equal to `lastNum`

```
int ChooseNewNumber(lastNum){
    minVal = 0;
    maxVal = N;
    if(minVal > lastNum || lastNum > maxVal){ 
        //if lastNum is outside range then just take full range
        return RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(minVal, maxVal);
    }
    random = RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(minVal, maxVal-1);
    if(lastNum <= random) random++;
    return random;
}
```

Comment: Upon first reading, I thought that this might introduce some bias or other nastiness. I wanted to suggest an alternative: generate a random number between [0, size_of_range-1] and interpret that as an index into the range … but then I immediately realized that that's the same thing, so, now I am convinced that there is no bias in your method. And it's much simpler!

Comment: Hmm. I've used the increment approach in the past, but I switched to the random offset after concluding that it doubled the odds of `lastNum+1` being chosen. Can you explain why this doesn't bias the result?

Also, as specified in the question, `lastNum` will always be in `[minVal, maxVal]`, so the simple full range approach will never be used.

Comment: @ReignofError no because if `RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(minVal, maxVal-1);` selects `lastNum+1` then it gets incremented to `lastNum+2`. That's why I increment the entire range between lastNum and maxVal.

Comment: @ReignofError Sounds like you had a `<` somewhere where you needed a `<=` or vice-versa

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: +0. This is overly complicated. There are too many paths and corner cases to test for a simple function like this. Also, the next fellow who will have to read your code will scratch his/her head during ten minutes before being sure this works as intended.

Answer (score 6):

Just choose between 1 and `N` and return 0 if the value is `lastNum`.

```
int ChooseNewNumber(lastNum){ 
    random = RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(1, N);
    if (random == lastNum) {
        return 0;
    }
    return random;
}
```

Or the shorter version, if you prefer:

```
int ChooseNewNumber(lastNum){
    random = RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(1, N);
    return (random == lastNum ? 0 : random);
}
```

### The generic answer (EDIT)

There was a little confusion about why I did actually wrote 0 and 1 instead of `minVal` and `maxVal`. For my defense, I found the original question equally confusing ;-) (cf. [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264675/choosing-a-random-integer-in-a-range-such-that-it-doesnt-equal-a-particular-num#comment538952_264675)).
Here is a modified version, with those variables given as parameters and with all assumptions explicitly checked:

```
int ChooseNewNumber(minVal, maxVal, lastNum){

    assert(minVal =< lastNum);
    assert(lastNum =< maxVal);
    assert(minVal < maxVal); /* there is at least one value */

    random = RandomIntWithinInclusiveRange(minVal, maxVal);
    return (random == lastNum ? (minVal + 1) : random);
}
```

Note however that since `lastNum` is supposed to be the last number picked, we could safely assume that it belongs to the intended interval.

Below, I still assume that `minVal` is 0 and `maxVal` is `N`, which makes sense in my example and keeps the explanation simpler.

### Explanation

Image a deck of 4 cards:

```
ABXD
```

X is at position `lastNum`.

Then, you want to pick only A,B or D.

This is equivalent to picking a random card in this set,

```
XBAD
```

... where you would swap `lastNum` and 0 and choose an element between 1 and `N`.

But in fact, you can do this without actually swapping elements.

Comment: Nice simple solution. I like it. And not just because I was going to post this exact same thing had you not already done so. ;-)

Comment: +1 This and ratchet freak's answers are two takes on same approach: map "N random outcomes" to "N random outcomes that exclude some value". In your case, you map lastNum to 0, and in ratchet freak's solution, he maps lastNum and up to the number +1. lastNum gets skipped either way. Either way is great because it only requires a single random generation and a single "if"

Comment: @RobY This is the same idea, but I still find that mine is a little more straightforward. Look: no need to compute N-1, no range check, no increment, no inequality test. The shifting done by ratchet freak's is maybe a little too "clever" and I did find it confusing at first sight (the two first comments say how people wasn't easily convinced there is no bias).

Comment: @Chris My actual first name is Chris, are you me ;-) ?

Comment: @coredump: maybe... ;-)

Comment: @coredump +1 I like this method; it's elegant (although technically the `1` should be `minVal+1` and the `0` should be `minVal`, but that's a trivial change). If I could choose two answers to the question, this would be one of them.

Comment: @ReignofError Maybe I should have answered the question faster, I don't know. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for the scrabble method:

1. Generate a list of numbers from 1-N;
2. Select a random item from this list;
3. Remove this item from the list;
4. Use the modified list when you need your next number.

It is simply impossible to draw the same number twice in a row, because the number is not in the list anymore. It is similar to what happens in games like Scrabble or Rummy.

in C# code (untested):

```
//do this during the setup phase
List<int> numberRange = Enumerable.Range(0, N).ToList();
Random random = new Random(); //Or your random implementation of choice

//Do this when you need a number
int index = random.Next(numberRange.Count);
int chosenNumber = numberRange[index];
numberRange.Remove(chosenNumber);
return chosenNumber;
```

Please note that this scales linearly in memory with N, and in time with N when generating the list. It is to be used if you need to ensure that you don't have the same item twice. If you don't want to pull the same number twice in a row (but you still want the number before the last number to be an option), you need to keep the original list and remove the last item using Except() BEFORE you generate your index.